# Allow php files to be accessed in laravel public folder

Tags: apache, laravel, roxy-fileman

I have a Laravel project that using Roxy Fileman as file manager. I put the files of Roxy Fileman under the public folder

```
/public/fileman
```

so I can access it by

```
<ifarame src="my.domain/fileman/index.html"></iframe>
```

the iframe will load data from PHP files in the plugin folder which located at

```
/public/fileman/php
```

It works well on my local XAMPP server but says `E_LoadingAjax php/dirtree.php` on my linux server, and returns 404 when I try directly access these files

I assume it is because PHP files are blocked from direct access for security reasons. 
Then how can I allow this specific folder to be accessed? or what is a better approach to use Roxy Fileman in laravel?

`.htaccess` comes with Laravel:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Open up *composer.json* and find section with **autoload**, and add **files** array, see example below (I created folder `folder` inside `public` folder which contains file `tst.php`) so I have public/folder/tst.php

Now when I visit  `1.1.1.1/folder/tst.php` PHP interprets me the code.

```
.
.
.

"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
    },
    "files": [
            "public/folder/"
    ]
},
.
.
.
```

Comment: this does not work for me, it allows me directly access the folder, but still give 404 to php files. Also it gives error if i do composer install

Comment: composer dump-autoload -o

Comment: after this you also have to create a Procfile and add these lines web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/